# Make a queue for user access same folder Lotus scripts

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have some problem about my folder that's contain document from searching , and document in this folder will  removed after show to user see. I didn't have Idea for this problem if many user access to folder in same time. How should I solve this problem. but which one Idea is create a folder for current user.

************ Explain my question*****************
thank you for all suggestion , maybe my question is not cover my problem or my question is not clear .Then may I describe again here if you understand like this it's okay.  The simple from my searching ,I have 1 View and 1 Folder per searching 1 times. The flow is when user click search button , backend will  take do like this. Save document from searching in variable and put in folder, Dialog will show folder that's contain document.and will remove all document after user click close. I think my problem is  if user access same time but must use same folder to contain document from search. then make the result not correct

Comment: How many users does this solution need to account for?

Comment: number of account depend on that's user access that's time and sometime is access same time.

Comment: What is the maximum??

Comment: Now I'm not sure for maximum , In organize staff maybe can access same time in big number.  Then if I'm not sure about number , How should I do? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Readers field on the document will do exactly what you want.  Just put the user's name in the field (preferably as a multi-value along with another user, group or role.)  Then when you want to prevent the user from seeing the document, you can either remove his name from the field or delete the document.

Comment: This is why I asked how many users there are. Using ReaderNames fields for this could be unwieldy if it's a large number of users. The same is true with an ordinary Names field and a view set up with the 'show single category' feature. I'd consider either of those to be a reasonable solution, but not if there are hundreds of users. Also, the number of documents matters, because in both cases the view slows down if it gets really big. (That's more of a problem with ReaderNames than with show-single-category, though.)

Comment: OP's question to me implies that there is one document per user (the result of a search.)  Since the Readers field is only the document, if that's indeed the case, the number of users is irrelevant.

Comment: Agreed. But since deleting the document would be the obvious solution for that, and since the OP mentioned considering creating a folder per user, I didn't think that was the case.

Comment: Right, creating a folder per user would be a bad idea and you're right, if that's OP's plan, then the number of users would be a consideration.  One benefit of the Readers field approach is that you don't have to delete the document right away, just change the Readers and then let it sit until a scheduled task removes it.

Comment: thank you for all suggestion , maybe my question is not cover my problem or my question is not clear . The simple from my searching ,I have 1 View and 1 folder per searching 1 times. The flow is when user click search button , backend will  take do like this.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion , The basic for solve my problem I have to use username when user access to crease unique folder for contain document while searching . then this can solve this problem for correct result from searching . and Could you read my question again. Cuz the last question I have to explain more about my problem. thank you again for my mistake cuz I'm a new for Lotus notes .

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should *not* implement this feature. There's no good way to do it.

Instead, you should train your users how to use this Notes client feature, which lets them toggle the view so that they either see all documents, or only the documents that they have not read yet:

[image: View-Show-Unread]

Comment: thank you for your suggestion , The basic for solve my problem I have to use username when user access to crease unique folder for contain document while searching . then this can solve this problem for correct result from searching . and Could you read my question again. Cuz the last question I have to explain more about my problem. thank you again for my mistake cuz I'm a new for Lotus notes .